# Protractor: How to handle with "element is not clickable at point (x,y), Other element would receive the click"

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on the following button, locators: 
css `div.d-flex > [_ngcontent-c1] > .navbar-toggler` 
and Xpath `//div[@class='container d-flex justify-content-between']/span[1]/a[1]`

I also updated the chrome driver using the command:webdriver-manager update 
Then, I have: version chromedriver_79.0.3945.36 
geckodriver version v0.26.0 
Chome Version 79.0.3945.88

When I run the protractor, I got the error:

> *Failed: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1157, 20). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)*

Here is the code I tried:

```
it('should return to the main menu', function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1284, 684);
        var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var elem = element(by.css('span:nth-of-type(2)>span>a>svg'));

        browser.driver.wait(function () {
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem), 10000);
            return elem;
        });

    elem.click();

})
```

The original code (without the wait) is

```
    it('should return to the main menu', function () {
      element(by.css('.fa-chevron-left')).click();                                                   
   });
```

And then, I got this error:

> *Failed: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (137, 23). Other
>   element would receive the click: ...
>         (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)*

The interesting is,the click on this button is working in other parts of the page.

Answer (score 4):

This error doesn't have anything to do with chrome version. The problem is that the element that you are trying to click has another element above it. This might not visually look like it but there can be a container or a web element that is above that element. See if you can find which element would receive the click. You might be able to find it on the error log. See if clicking that element would give you the same result that you require.

Comment: Hi @Sankalan, thank you for your support, I add sleep() before the click on the button, and it is working fine

Comment: @IngriddBrito you should move your code to use async await so that you can do away with browser.sleep() altogether. You can check how to do it [here](https://medium.com/@anandujjwal/end-to-end-testing-using-protractor-with-async-await-46dc11d948d0)

Answer (score 2):

Click on the element using  javascript executor:

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', elem);
```